# How do I access all elements with same class but no parent class in cheerio

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

```
<div class="answer">
    <div>first</div>
</div>

<div class="answer">
    <div>second</div>
</div>

<div class="answer">
    <div>third</div>
</div>
```

I have to access all the elements with class=answer

Comment: `$('.answer')` will get all elements with the class "answer". https://cheerio.js.org/#selectors

Comment: @evolutionxbox how do I convert it into an array or loop through it?

Comment: https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#each is likely how you would loop through them. Please do make sure to search through the documentation

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if cheer.io can or not but in jQuery you can use this:

```js
$("html").findAll(".answer")
```

i think it will work because every XML document must have a supreme tag like `document.documentElement`